# Conversion error from uint to int in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I have been trying to learn solidity.

Wrote a simple program as shown below

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.12 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
    int[] staticArray = [int(1), int(2), int(3), int(4), int(5)];

    function getStaticArray(int _pos) public view returns(int) {
        int ret = staticArray[_pos];
        return ret;
    }
}
```

But giving following conversion error for some reason:

> TypeError: Type int256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type
> uint256.
>
> --> first.sol:13:31:
>
> |
>
> 13 | int ret = staticArray[_pos];
>
> | ^^^^

Which I am not sure why this error is thrown. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use uint instead of int when you are using index in an array.

```
function getStaticArray(uint _pos) public view returns(int) {
    int ret = staticArray[_pos];
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an index to an array must be non-negative, the Solidity compiler requires it to be unsigned.

Therefore, you need to change `int _pos` to `uint _pos`.

Note that `uint` is an alias to `uint256`, and that you can generally use any other unsigned type.